# How can I tie my namespaces to my folder hierarchy in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, namespaces

I am currently learning about namespaces, the usage of `use` and the likes, but for some reason, I can't quite get it.

I have this structure:

```
main_project
  -inc
    -..
    -..
    -Social
      -interfaces
         -[*]social_scrape.php
         -[*]social_post.php
      -[*]instagram.php
      -[*]posts.php
    -..
```

In short, I have the folder `inc` from **which I auto-load (it's a for loop that `require_once` a bunch of files from a list) only these files:**

`~path/inc/Social/instagram.php + posts.php`

Do keep in mind, **I am not loading the files in the Interfaces folder.** Now, my current `instagram.php` looks exactly like this:

```
<?php

namespace Social_Life;


interface Scrape_Interface {

    public function build_endpoint();

    public function get_json();

    public function get_data();
}

class Scrape_Instagram implements Scrape_Interface {}
```

But this is bad in terms of OOP. The interface should be a contract that other classes should be able to use, as such, it should be agnostic of my `instagram.php` file. So, I decided to move it into:

`~path/inc/Social/Interfaces/social_scrape.php` and initialize it (without loading the file from the autoloader) like this:

`use Social_Life\Interfaces\Social_Scrape\Scrape_Interface;` where my new **scrape_interface.php** file looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace Social_Life\Interfaces\Social_Scrape;

interface Scrape_Interface {

    public function build_endpoint();

    public function get_json();

    public function get_data();
}
```

But this fails:

```
Fatal error: Interface 'Social_Life\Interfaces\Social_Scrape\Scrape_Interface' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\s-master\inc\Social\instagram.php on line 7
```

Comment: Could you clearify fails?

Comment: @RolandStarke Hi! Not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: Like e.g. does your PC start burning? ;)

Comment: @RolandStarke Indeed it's burning. I've added the error I'm getting exactly.

Comment: Mmh looks like your autoloader does not load the interface. take a look at  http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php . Requiring a predefined list of files is usually not the way an autoloader works.

Comment: Regarding the fire I would unplug the power and cover the PC with a blanket.

Answer (score 2):

You've only solved 2/3 of the problem, namespacing and file hierarchy, which are meaningless without something that maps a namespaced class name to a file in that hierarchy and loads in automatically. An autoloader.

You can write your own and register it with [`spl_autoload_register()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php), but what I would suggest instead of that is bringing your namespacing and file hierarchy into line with [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) and use [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) as the autoloader. Now your code is more easily reusable and redistributable, and you can leverage Composer to pull in and update your dependencies, or publish your code for others to use.

So, for example, we'd want to adjust the hierarchy slightly:

```
main_project/
  -inc/
    -Social/
      -Interfaces/
         -Social_Scrape.php // joshc\social_scrape\Social\Interfaces\Social_Scrape
         -Social_Post.php   // joshc\social_scrape\Social\Interfaces\Social_Post
      -Instagram.php        // joshc\social_scrape\Social\Instagram
      -Posts.php            // joshc\social_scrape\Social\Posts
  -composer.json
  -vendor/
  -example.php
```

Note that the filename casing needs to match the class and declared namespace.

And your minimal `composer.json` would look something like:

```
{
    "name": "joshc/social_life",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "joshc\\social_life\\": "inc/"
        }
    }
}
```

Which defines that the namespace `joshc\social_life` is rooted in the `inc/` directory relative to where `composer.json` is located. Note that PSR-4 mandates that you declare a vendor namespace [eg: joshc] and convention is that the next level is the package name. [eg: social_life]

Running `composer install` generates the composer autoloader.

An example class file, `Social_Scrape.php`:

```
<?php
namespace joshc\social_life\Social\Interfaces;

interface Social_Scrape { ... }
```

And `example.php`:

```
<?php
require(__DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php');
use joshc\social_life\Social\Interfaces\Social_Scrape;

class Scrapey implements Social_Scrape { ... }
```

Now all you need to worry about is that `vendor/autoload.php` is included somewhere in your application code and you don't have to loop through every file in your hierarchy at any point.

Comment: Thanks! For now, my autoloader is a simple require from a list of files, as follows: https://pastebin.com/nNYzdKbT . I'd like to use this **for now**. In contrast with your answer, all I'd have to do is really just add the files and fix the namespaces, correct?